# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors - not using $ in the code

Tags: r, operators

As you can see there is no $ in my lines.
However when I try to run the last line it gives me the error of $ blabla atomic. 
In the beginning I had some $ in there but then I changed everything to the [] format.
It still gives me the error.
**Any idea why?**

Attached the code that I used.

```
library(rugarch)
library(xts)
#uploading and preparing the data
data_sentivola<-read.csv("Some Path")

data_sentivola_INT <- data_sentivola[data_sentivola[,"ticker"] == "INTC",]
xts_sentivola_INTC <- xts(data_sentivola_INT[,c("return","rv")], order.by=as.Date(data_sentivola_INT[,"Date"]))


#Specifying the realGARCH model
spec <- ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = FALSE), variance.model = list(model = 'realGARCH', garchOrder = c(1, 1)))  
fit<- ugarchfit(spec, xts_sentivola_INTC[,"return"]*100, solver = "hybrid", realizedVol = xts_sentivola_INTC[,"rv"]*100)
```

The error message then looks like that

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Without data we can't run and test the code. After you get the error run `traceback()` to see where it's coming from. It's likely that one of the functions you are using has the `$` code inside.

Comment: The error is from internal code of one of the functions you are using. My guess is that you pass to a function expecting a data.frame or list some different (wrong) data structure.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I did not do a correct xts transformation and because of that it threw the error. Thanks for bringing me on the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch : this looks like you are using `vec[,my_var]` (equivalent to `vec$my_var`) on a vector (where the syntax is somethin along `vec[3]`) and not a data.frame .